# can I expose a WCF service from an application runing in visual studio(with F5, run)?

Tags: wcf

If I run a WCF application which exposes a service in visual studio, is it possible to consume the service from an asp.net application running on another computer? How can I determine the address of the WSDL published by the WCF service in order to add a reference to it in the ASP.NET application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your service is an ASP.NET application and you are hosting it with the built-in development server, refer to Kalus's answer.  However, if you have IIS installed locally, you can reconfigure your project settings so that the application is hosted by IIS for debugging instead of the built-in development server.

If you are writing a standalone WinForms or Console application, then the responsibility will be on you to select an endpoint and binding, whereas with an ASP.NET application, those parameters will come from IIS or the Dev server (the protocol will always be HTTP/HTTPS, and the port number will be set by IIS or randomly generated by the Dev server).  So in a standalone application, you will have to configure which binding (basicHttp, wsHttp, netTcp, etc.) and an appropriate hosting endpoint (http://hostname/MyService or net.tcp://hostname:port/MyService).  But yes, if the service is hosted by a standalone application, it will be accessible from other computers.

Refer to this overview here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx

Answer (score 0):

According to @Kent Boogart's comment below, the asp.net development server can only be used for local requests. So you will need to configure your web service to run in IIS if you want to call it from another machine.

Comment: ASP.NET dev server serves local traffic only.

Comment: Further to that, it sounds as though he's hosting the WCF service outside of ASP.NET (perhaps in a console app) and is trying to consume from an ASP.NET app. Not really clear.